# pyspark nested arrays explode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame as follows:

```python
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (
            1, 
            "2017-12-03", 
            """{"1":[{"john":[12443,12441],"james":[14380,14379,13463],"mike":[15284,15280]}],"2":[{"brian":[15284,15280],"julio":[15284],"org":[]}]}"""
        ),
        (
            2, 
            "2017-12-04", 
            """{"1":[{"john":[12443,12441],"james":[14380,14379,13463],"mike":[15284,15280]}],"2":[{"brian":[15284,15280]}]}"""
        )
    ],
    ("id", "date", "users")
)
```

and I have a function that loads as json:

```python
@udf("map<string, array<string>>")
def parse(s):
    try:
        return json.loads(s)
    except:
        pass
```

When I select the top level it looks fine but is dropping double quotes for the users:

```python
df.select("id", "date", explode(parse("users")).alias("tier_id", "user_list")).show()

+---+----------+-------+--------------------+
| id|      date|tier_id|           user_list|
+---+----------+-------+--------------------+
|  1|2017-12-03|      1|[{john=[12443, 12...|
|  1|2017-12-03|      2|[{julio=[15284], ...|
|  2|2017-12-04|      1|[{john=[12443, 12...|
|  2|2017-12-04|      2|[{brian=[15284, 1...|
+---+----------+-------+--------------------+
```

When I try to explode the users I get following error message:

```python
df.select("id", "date", explode(parse("users")).alias("tier_id", "user_list"))\
    .withColumn("user_list", explode("user_list")).alias("user", "drill").show()

TypeError: alias() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I don't think it can explode the user_list because all the double quotes are dropped.
How can I get this working please?

Comment: Misplaced closing bracket  `.withColumn("user_list", explode("user_list").alias("user", "drill"))`

Comment: Thanks - but I get message now of :  u"Generators are not supported when it's nested in expressions, but got: multialias(explode(user_list));

Comment: the json is not valid to be used as json

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your udf is returning an array of strings instead of an array of maps. You could parse the string with the json library again, or you could just change your udf to return the proper type:

```
@udf("map<string, array<map<string, array<int>>>>")
def parse(s):
    try:
        return json.loads(s)
    except:
        pass
```

That will return the expected type (array of dictionaries, with string keys and values of integer arrays).

```
df.select("id", "date", explode(parse("users")).alias("tier_id", "user_list"))\
    .withColumn("user_list", explode("user_list"))\
    .select("id", "date", "tier_id", explode("user_list").alias("user", "drill")).show()

# +---+----------+-------+-----+--------------------+
# | id|      date|tier_id| user|               drill|
# +---+----------+-------+-----+--------------------+
# |  1|2017-12-03|      1| john|      [12443, 12441]|
# |  1|2017-12-03|      1| mike|      [15284, 15280]|
# |  1|2017-12-03|      1|james|[14380, 14379, 13...|
# |  1|2017-12-03|      2|julio|             [15284]|
# |  1|2017-12-03|      2|brian|      [15284, 15280]|
# |  1|2017-12-03|      2|  org|                  []|
# |  2|2017-12-04|      1| john|      [12443, 12441]|
# |  2|2017-12-04|      1| mike|      [15284, 15280]|
# |  2|2017-12-04|      1|james|[14380, 14379, 13...|
# |  2|2017-12-04|      2|brian|      [15284, 15280]|
# +---+----------+-------+-----+--------------------+
```

Note that you need to explode `user_list` twice because it starts as an array of maps, not a map type.

Comment: Thanks I tried that but get the following message where it is creating the udf:   ValueError: The map type string format is: 'map<key_type,value_type>', but got: map<string, array<map<string, array<int>>>>

Comment: Which version of spark are you using? It works as expected for me in 2.3. When you do df.printSchema(), do you get

 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- users: string (nullable = true) ?